# Robot as word processor - looking for old short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots, artificial-intelligence

Looking for an old short story where a publishing company buys a robot to help with copy-editing (typing on a manual type-writer...). The robot then ends up copy-editing, then writing the stories, then gets "returned" because it's taking someone's job, and is better than it's human counterparts.

I love this story because they get everything right about modern word processors... except they have a physical robot to do it on a type writer... unfortunately, I can't remember the author or the title.

Comment: Do you recall what kind of stuff they were publishing? Was it science fiction?

Answer (score 8):

This could be Asimov's story [*Galley Slave*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galley_Slave), one of the Susan Calvin series.

> The story is a courtroom drama. It opens in 2033, with Simon
>   Ninheimer, a professor of sociology, suing US Robots for loss of
>   professional reputation. He contends that robot EZ-27 (aka "Easy"),
>   whilst leased to Northeastern University for use as a proofreader,
>   deliberately altered and rewrote parts of his book Social Tensions
>   Involved in Space Flight and their Resolution whilst checking the
>   galley proofs (hence the title). Ninheimer holds that the alterations
>   to his book make him appear an incompetent scholar who has
>   misrepresented the work of his professional colleagues in fields such
>   as criminal justice in absurd ways.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but it doesn't seem to fit most of the plot in the question. Unless the OP misremembers the bulk of the story.

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time. Personally I thought the "robot as copy-editor" was sufficient to make it a match.

Comment: It seemed a lot like "Galley Slave" to me, too.  But "The robot then ends up copy-editing, then writing the stories, then gets "returned" because it's taking someone's job, and is better than it's human counterparts." doesn't exactly match.  And I think I remember a similar questin.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a similar question:

"https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155109/looking-for-short-story-about-a-writing-machine"

Your plot summary seems like "Galley Slave" to me but with some differences.  It is possible that you're remembering both "[Galley Slave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galley_Slave)" *and* "[Fault-Intolerant](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42270)" and conflating details of both.